# Ajax отправка формы без обработчика

Tags: javascript, ajax

может я и глупость спрашиваю, но всё таки может кто то мне поможет готовым кодом.
У меня страницы прогружаются на ajax:

```
 <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="startAjax('doc.php');doc();">Создать</a></li>
```

Вывод идёт в `<div id="printResult"></div>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startAjax(url){
  var request;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if(window.ActiveXObject){
      request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
  } else {
      return;
  }
 
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        switch (request.readyState) {

          case 4:{

           if(request.status==200){  
 document.getElementById("printResult").innerHTML =' '+request.responseText+'  ';
                     }else if(request.status==404){
        relogin(onSuccess);
    }
           
            break
            }
        }      
    }
    request.open ('GET', url, true);
    request.send ('');
  }
  function print_console(text){
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += text;
  }
</script>
```

А как мне сделать так же что бы форма прогружалась через этот же ajax и вывод в `<div id="printResult"></div>` ?
Вот стандартная с перезагрузкой:

```
  <form  action="infor.php" method="POST" class="sidebar-form">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="viezs_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Номер выезда">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" name="" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat">
              <i class="fa fa-car"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Буду очень раз готовому решению, так у меня будет три таких формы. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, но если вы хотите, чтобы форма не перезагружалась после отправки данных на сервер, то надо поменять тип кнопки на button и повешать обработчик на событие клик:

```js
$("body").on("click", "#search-btn", function(){
  // Здесь ajax-запрос
});
```

```html
<form  action="infor.php" method="POST" class="sidebar-form">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="viezs_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Номер выезда">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" name="" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat">
              <i class="fa fa-car"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а ajax-запрос какой нужно что бы в <div id="printResult"></div> отображалось? Который я указал в начале не работает